# How to fix installing expo-cli

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to install expo-cli using npm and its giving me an error.
I have installed it using yarn and it installed succesfully and yet it is saying 'expo is not recognise as an internal or external command'.

I have tried 'npm install expo-cli -g' gives an error.
I tried yarn and it install succesfully and yet it doesn't recognise expo.
I have uninstalling node.js and reinstalling it still doesn't help.

**npm install -g expo-cli**

npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.4.4:  As of Babel 7.4.0, this
npm WARN deprecated package has been deprecated in favor of directly
npm WARN deprecated including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript
npm WARN deprecated features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime
npm WARN deprecated (needed to use transpiled generator functions):
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated   > import "core-js/stable";
npm WARN deprecated   > import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Isma'il\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-25T15_40_22_685Z-debug.log

Answer (score 2):

you can install with the sudo permissions

```
sudo npm install expo-cli -g
```